# Using map as an input to random forest classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a problem using sklearn module in python. I'm trying to use random forest classifier for classification of 16 different class using the following code:

```
count = 0
for line in lines:
    tokens = line.strip().split(",")
    if count < TRAINING_SIZE:
        X.append(map(float, tokens[0:NUM_PCA]))
        if CLASSIFICATION_TYPE == 2:
            y.append(int(tokens[len(tokens)-1]))
        elif int(tokens[len(tokens)-1]) == 1:
            y.append(0)
        else:
            y.append(1)
        count += 1
    else:
        test_X.append(map(float, tokens[0:NUM_PCA]))
        if CLASSIFICATION_TYPE == 2:
            test_y.append(int(tokens[len(tokens)-1]))
        elif int(tokens[len(tokens)-1]) == 1:
            test_y.append(0)
        else:
            test_y.append(1)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=1, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X,y)

train_predictions = clf.predict(X)
test_predictions = clf.predict(test_X)
```

But it returns an error indicating:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'

How can I use map in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change:

```
X.append(map(float, tokens[0:NUM_PCA]))
```

to:

```
X.append([float(tok) for tok in tokens[0:NUM_PCA]])
```

the issue should be fixed.

Notice that you have to do the same for `test_X.append(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your help.